# Database tool for searching GPS location and Lightroom tags?

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-catalog, tagging, reverse-geocoding

## Context

I'm use to programming and using SQL commands to get data from a database or other structure.

## Question

Is there a tool that allows me to say count (and possibly show) all images (in a Lightroom catalog) at a given location with a certain tag? (E.g. the tag "sunset" and at a GPS coordinate). I know Lightroom can sort by time, camera and other gear but I'm not sure the best approach for that.

Comment: I'm not a Lightroom user, but it looks like its catalogue files are SQLite databases. So theoretically, any tool you have that can query an SQLite file can query a Lightroom catalogue file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really easy to do: simply combine filters.

- In the Map module, click the set of images you want to search. More than one location? Zoom out, and/or shift+click.
- In the Library module, enable Metadata filters and filter by Keyword (tag)

You can combine by any/many filters to find the photos you want. Further restrict this result by date, star rating, or camera, for example.

Answer (score 0):

And what about Adobe Bridge ? 
It could sort/filter by : file type, date, profile etc. But I'm affraid that there is no GPS filter. I don't have any picture with GPS tag, so can't check it.